# WooCommmerce filtering classes for div and ul generated by [products] shortcode

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm creating a custom WooCommerce shop page with the [products] shortcode, and I've filtered the classes applied to individual product `<li>` using the `woocommerce_post_class` filter hook.

I haven't been able to figure out where in the *wc-template-functions.php* file the class lists are generated for the containing `<div>` and `<ul>` elements:

```
<div class="woocommerce columns-1 ">
<ul class="products columns-1">
```

Are filter hooks available to customize these class lists?

Alternatively, which template file has to be edited to customize the class lists for these elements?

I'm also wondering what the best practice is for limiting these filter hooks to only be executed when called by this particular [products] shortcode.

Can I pass a custom parameter through the [products] shortcode and check its value in the filter hook?

Comment: you can pass class to your shortcode - https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#examples-of-product-scenarios

Comment: To customize the class lists for the <div> and <ul> elements in WooCommerce, you need to override the loop/loop-start.php template in your child theme, and there are no direct filter hooks for these specific classes.

Comment: Thanks.  Can I pass a custom parameter through the [products] shortcode and check its value in the filter hook?